# Can one say amen to a blessing invoked by a Christian?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, christianity

I was watching the blessings recited by clergy of various religions at the currently ongoing Republican National Convention to see if the blessings were made generally to G-d, or if the one giving the blessing would invoke powers antithetical to Judaism, such as the trinity.

Some were general, but there was (at least) one blessing that mentioned Jesus as a protector.  Obviously, a Jew may not believe in or say amen to such a blessing.  But may one answer amen to a blessing recited by one who believes the idea of Jesus as a power, but makes a general blessing to "god"?

Additionally, there was a blessing (from a Greek Orthodox priest) which made no mention of an additional power besides a god, but performed the [Sign of the Cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_of_the_Cross) as he was completing the blessing.  Would this affect responding to his blessing?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89/5

Comment: And also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12235/5

Comment: See this as well: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6683/1569

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell you if this definitely applies, but the Shulchan Aruch ([OC 215:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=239&hilite=)) seems to be clear that one should not recite Amen if there is reason to believe that the one making the blessing had in mind something other than the Jewish conception of God.

Comment: The Rama there says that you say amen after **an idol worshiper**, if you heard the full brachah

Comment: Dov, there doesn't seem to be any indication from the SA since that is referring to not hearing the entire bracha.  Also, @ba, that Rema seems to be talking about someone who worships an idol named, say, Shazam!, but make an appropriate blessing to G-d.  In my case, he uses the word god implying the Almighty, but has a different idea of what that is. Although Mishna Berura SK10 there may deal with my case.

Comment: Dov, please incorporate how the Mishna Berura learns the SA (to come out like you), though we still need to hash out if the Gra would argue in my case as well.

Comment: @ba the Rema refers to someone who made a bracha the same way we do, so it is reasonable to assume he's talking about the same God.

Comment: @YDK My point was not to say that the Shulchan Aruch says this, but that it is clearly implied. The reasoning there is that we aren't sure he was talking about our God.

Comment: A cursory reading of the SA would assume the author is continuing the same case- where one did not hear the entire blessing, with the exception of the final case (or 2 acc. to MB) which is a regular Jew who changed the required text of an instituted blessing albeit the entire blessing was said.  The MB, however, applies the final case(s) retroactively where the Kusi/apikorus said the entire blessing as well, but their intent may be different.  I don't know believe that approach is muchrach.

Comment: I've even heard people go so far as to say that we should say amen to "allahu akhbar" by muslims, because this means "G-d is great"

Comment: @Sean A muslim saying Allah is great is referring to the same being we refer to when we say God is great.