# Singing or listening to non-Jewish religious music

Tags: halacha, gentiles, avodah-zarah, music

Is it permissible to listen or sing non-Jewish religious music so long as praise and worship is only expressed to Hashem and this is clear and/or your intention is only to praise G-d and no one else?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6677/1569

Comment: According to Kabala music comes from the heavenly spheres and reflects the person who created it. This is why many Jews will not listen to non-jewish music even without any religious themes. So it's not [just] the intention of the listener to only praise God, but also the intention of the person who sang the music.

Comment: What's an example?  Are you talking about, e.g., psalm texts set by Christian composers?  Praise of (a generic) "God" not from particular sources and by non-Jewish composers?  How do you know it's our God?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11347

Answer (score 2):

The apparent ruling of [Rabbi Israel Moses Hazan](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/index.php?table_name=seforim_database&function=details&where_field=id&where_value=153) notwithstanding it seem very difficult to argue that such a practice is permitted.

Rabbi Shlomo Aviner *shlita* has [ruled that it is forbidden](http://www.ravaviner.com/2011/01/shut-sms-97.html) citing Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 167:1

Comment: What if there's no mention of any idolatry? Only God.