# Would it be okay to wear a yarmulke under a graduation cap?

Tags: kippa-yarmulka

I graduate from high school tomorrow, and I was wondering if it was acceptable to wear a yarmulke underneath my graduation cap. I lean more towards reform, not that that matters :)

Thanks y’all!

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128394

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

To answer the question, yes, it is not at all unusual for someone to wear a hat or another type of covering over their yarmulke. It does not conflict with the halacha.

Essentially, the reason for covering one's head is because of the gemara in [Shabbat (156b)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=156b&format=pdf) (Credit to [Baal Shemot Tovot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1172/baal-shemot-tovot) for translation) which states:

> כסי רישיך כי היכי דתיהוי עלך אימתא דשמיא

> "Cover your head so that there will be on you fear of heavens"

This is quoted in the Shulchan Aruch as Halacha (O"C 2:6). Therefore, as long as you have your yarmulke covering on your head which imbues you with the "fear of havens", then you are fulfilling this, and thus, it is not a halachic issue if you have a hat over it.

It's very common to wear a hat over your yarmulke and many Orthodox and Haredi Jews do it all the time. See this [article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3102418/jewish/Why-Wear-Both-a-Kippah-and-a-Hat.htm) on Chabad website which talks more about its spiritual significance and history.

Comment: I'm not sure if the article I linked is properly clickable, so I'll just copy paste it here: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3102418/jewish/Why-Wear-Both-a-Kippah-and-a-Hat.htm

Comment: One additional point not covered in this answer is that a yarmulke may not be required. The graduation cap itself is considered a head-covering, so one may place the yarmulke in one's pocket until after the graduation.

Comment: @joshwaxman it sounds like the questioner doesn't normally cover his head, but would like to specifically wear a yarmulka to his graduation as a point of pride in his faith. To which we say -- sure!