# Ear Piercing of Jewish slave that wants to stay a slave a mum?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, slave-serve-eved-avadim

I heard in a daf yomi shiur (on kedushin 21b) that a koen can not want to stay a slave (one opinion says it is because he the Ear Piercing will make him have a mum

What Ear Piercing makes a mum?

Does a girls usual Piercing make her have a mum?

Did the Piercing that was given to a slave close up? (If yes did that remove the mum)

[16-different-types-of-ear-piercings](http://listsurge.com/top-16-different-types-of-ear-piercings/)

[Parts of the Ear](https://www.infovisual.info/03/048_en.html)

Related [Getting body piercings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29293/5120)

Comment: "Does a girls usual Piercing make her have a mum?" Even if so, does it matter? (Maybe to _Yiftach_. `:-)`)

Comment: See my post [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/getting-body-piercings) I explain the percing ear concerning mum.

Comment: @msh210 nafka mina, Hamikadesh al minas sheain mum, also by a kohen Baal teshuva for avoda bmhaira byamainu (if the mumim will not yet be healed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. #### Mishna & Gemara

   Bechorot 37b.

   > ‏ ‏<sup>[1]</sup>‏ [משנה בדף ל"ז עמוד א': מתני' על אלו מומין שוחטין את הבכור נפגמה אזנו מן הסחוס אבל לא העור‏<sup>[2]</sup>‏ נסדקה אעפ''י שלא חסרה ניקבה מלא כרשינה או שיבשה איזהו יבשה כל שתנקב ואינה מוציאה טיפת דם ר' יוסי בן המשולם אומר יבשה שתהא נפרכת:]: ת''ר כמה נקיבת האוזן מלא כרשינה ר' יוסי בר' יהודה אומר בכעדשה‏<sup>[3]</sup>‏ ואיזו היא יבשה שאם תינקב ואינה מוציאה טיפת דם ר' יוסי בן המשולם אומר יבשה כדי שתהא נפרכת תנא קרובין דבריהן להיות שוין דבריהן דמאן אילימא דתנא קמא ור' יוסי בן המשולם טובא איכא אלא דתנא קמא ור' יוסי בר' יהודה כעדשה אין בציר מכעדשה לא ורמינהי {דברים טו-יז} מרצע‏<sup>[4]</sup>‏ אין לי אלא מרצע מנין לרבות הסול והסירה והמחט והמקדח והמכתב ת''ל {דברים טו-יז} ולקחת כל דבר שנלקח ביד דברי ר' יוסי בר' יהודה רבי אומר מרצע מה מרצע מיוחד של מתכת אף כל של מתכת וקתני סיפא א''ר יודן ברבי היה דורש כשהן רוצעין אין רוצעין אלא במילת‏<sup>[5]</sup>‏ וחכמים אומרים אין עבד עברי כהן נרצע מפני שנעשה בעל מום‏<sup>[6]</sup>‏ וא''ת במילת היו רוצעין היאך עבד כהן נעשה בעל מום הא אין רוצעין אלא בגובה של אוזן‏<sup>[7]</sup>‏ אמר רב חנא בר קטינא לא קשיא כאן לשחוט כאן לפסול‏<sup>[8]</sup>‏ 
   >   ‏

   [1] We know that the defects disqualifying a Korban are the defects disqualifying Cohanim (Mishna Bechorot 7, 1)
   [2] When his ear is damaged at the level of the cartilage, but not if damaged on the skin only.
   [3] 2 opinion for the minimal diameter of the hole witch will damage the ear and disqualify the Bechor Behema/Cohen. 1.- a seed called Karshina a bit larger than a lentil (Rashi); 2.- a lentil.
   [5] This opinion is that
   [4] Punch (a drill to make holes in leather)
   [5] According to Rabbi Yudan Berebi, one must pierce the lobe of the ear (a little hole in the lobe does not blemish)
   [6] The divergent view is that one must to pierce the cartilage. The proof is that Cohen does not be pierced because if pierced, he becomes blemished and does never recover his anterior status (The verse says And he will come back to his family, with all atributes of his family).
   [7] Although than we make the hole at the level of cartilage, we may make a little hole with a needle, witch does not blemishe (Rashi).
   [8] Even a little hole blemishes. But to allow the Shchita of a Bechor Passul, Chachomim are more stringent. But Cohen is Passul MideOrayita (Tosfot) with a little hole in cartilage of the ear.
2. #### Rambam (Sefer Kinyan, hilchot Avadim, Chapter 3, law 8)

   follows this conclusion:

   > ‏ עבד עברי כהן אינו נרצע מפני שנעשה בעל מום והרי הוא אומר ושב אל משפחתו לחזקה שהיה בה. ואינו שב לשררה שהיה בה:  ‏
   > A Hebrew servant who is a priest may not have his ear pierced, because this gives him a physical blemish that disqualifies him from service in the Temple, and Leviticus 25:41 states: "And he shall return to his family," to the status that he enjoyed previously. He does not, however, return to the position of authority that he previously held.
3. #### Conclusion

   Ear Piercing of Jewish slave who wants to stay a slave makes a hole on cartilage and makes a MUM. So it is prohibited to make this to a cohen slave (following some Acharonim, even if he was already baal mum).

Comment: What does schizza mean?

Comment: So it is [Helix_piercing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix_piercing) ?

Comment: And earlobe piercing is not a mum ?

Comment: helix piercing is a mum. all soft tissue piercing (soft = tenerus in loaze rishonim) do not make a mum. BTW cartilage is poorly irrigated and wounds of cartilage can lead to infections, to tearing.