# Can men get a piercing?

Tags: halacha, men-male, jewelry, lo-yilbash

Is an ear piercing begged isha? It’s very mainstream now to the point where I’m thinking that there’s a chance that it might be alright. Thoughts

Comment: Besides the beged isha problem, which perhaps is not relevant in certain locales, there is an issue of chavala (for beauty it is permitted for a woman, for a man it’s highly debatable) and the issue of chukas hagoyim.

Comment: related (and possible duplicate): [Getting body piercings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29293/11501)

Comment: Also a late [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) David. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Chatzkel why does gender affect if "beauty" is a reason to mutilate your body?

Comment: @DoubleAA see RSZ in Minchat Shlomo II:82 who makes that distinction

Comment: Forget about begged isha, now that I think about it why aren’t all piercings forbidden because of כתבת קעקע?

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud says:

> [On Shabbat], a tailor must not go out with a needle stuck in his garment, nor a carpenter with a chip in his ear. [Shabbat 11b]

Rashi informs us that men wore earrings that indicated their trades.

Body piercings are generally allowed by Jewish law, according to responsa by Rav Moshe Feinstein [Igrot Moshe Choshen Mishpat 2:66] and the Lubavitcher Rebbe [Likutei Sikhot, v20, p 568].  In areas where body piercing is practiced only by women, men may not do it. [Shulḥan Arukh, Yoreh Deah, 182:5]