# Are body piercings ok for a Jewish woman to get?

Tags: halacha, women

My S/O wants to get a piercing just so she feels good about herself. We got into a small argument 15 minutes ago as I told her not to and shouldn't, and she started getting a bit defensive saying that I'm trying to prevent her from expressing and being herself. She is observant herself but this is I guess one of those moments where she wants to be a bit rebellious or something, I don't know. I find her trying to be a bit rebellious despite being observant at the same time. Anyway, I don't know if it's ok for her to get one or not. Does anyone know?

Comment: We can answer here about what Halachic sources generally say that's relevant. Regarding whether it's OK *for your SO* is not something we can answer, as Mi Yodeya doesn't know her and isn't her rabbi. The extra-layer question - whether you should push your SO to not get a piercing - is even more complicated and is something you should take up with your rabbi.

Comment: @Isaac Moses i live in a small town with no Rov, that's why i asked on here. But thanks for clarifying it with me.

Comment: This is an excellent site if you guys wanna check it out https://www.deracheha.org/

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/getting-body-piercings?rq=1

Comment: See [yoatzot](https://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/757/) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2169) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/44085)

Comment: @Isaac the OP clearly isn't getting the message. I move to close anyway.

Comment: For the Halachic side of it, I'd say this question is basically a duplicate of "[Getting body piercings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29293/1368)", that @BID [linked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139736/are-body-piercings-ok-for-a-jewish-woman-to-get#comment466798_139736).

Answer (score 3):

Many body piercings are generally permitted.  For example, the Talmud says:

> [On Shabbat], a tailor must not go out with a needle stuck in his garment, nor a carpenter with a chip in his ear. [Shabbat 11b]  (Rashi adds that men wore earrings that indicated their trades.)

> -And these are women's ornaments: Necklaces, earrings, finger-rings... and nose-rings. [Shabbat 59b]

> -Girls may go out [on Shabbat] with ribbons, and even with chips in their ears.  [Mishnah, Shabbat 6:6]

> -[Consider] the case of a king who desired to marry a certain woman, but was told by people that she was poor, possessing only two nose-rings as her own. [Exodus Rabbah 15:3]

Other body piercings are also generally allowed, according to responsa by Rav Moshe Feinstein [Igrot Moshe Choshen Mishpat 2:66] and the Lubavitcher Rebbe. [Likutei Sikhot, v20, p 568]  In areas where body piercing is practiced only by women, men may not do it. [Shulcḥan Arukh, Yoreh Deah, 182:5]

Answer (score 1):

דת יהודית depends on local custom.

Stating that our foremother Rivkah seems to have had a nose ring which Shadal cites Rosenmueller as meaning with a piercing

Shadal Bereshit 24:22

> pendant (nezem). There is a nezem worn in the nose and a nezem worn on the ears. Here it is meant for the nose, as it is specified below: “I placed the pendant on her nose” [v. 47]. According to Rosenmueller, they used to pierce the nose and insert the nezem in it, and so Niebuhr saw the Arab women do. The verse is abbreviated and does not spell out that he took the pendant “and gave it to her,” or “placed it on her nose.”

Comment: In the linked question, @DoubleAA [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/getting-body-piercings#comment106591_29293) that the verse says 'על אפה' (rather than 'באפה'), and [further down](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/getting-body-piercings#comment107887_29293), I brought Ibn Ezra's commentary, which suggests how that could work.