# Nose rings allowed or not allowed?

Tags: minhag, women, clothing

The Torah states that Eliezer gave Rivka a golden nose ring...Based on the Torah it is allowed. What I want to know is why people do not accept this and discourage it.

Comment: You are making a definitive statement that this is not allowed. Please provide support for such a statement.

Comment: Why do you assume it is not allowed? i actually heard that up to about 150 years ago nose rings were common among jews in morocco.

Comment: Who are these people you are referring to? are there any specific groups that have declared that a nose ring is prohibited?

Comment: I don't see any one in Boro Park, Willi, Monroe, Flatbush with nose rings. I don't think anyone has outright prohibited it, I think people even if they would want to do it, are too afraid to stand out regardless if it is permitted halachically.

Comment: @chavatzellet Maybe they all happen to think it's ugly?

Comment: I think you know that probably isn't true.

Comment: @chavatzellet Are you talking to me? I don't think that isn't true. Maybe that's just my tastes though. Why anyone would feel a need to put metal through their body to feel pretty is beyond me.

Comment: @chavatzellet, People in "Boro Park, Willi, Monroe, Flatbush" have very defined social strictures about style and appearance. They don't include nose rings because they don't include a lot of variety, not because this particular one is more forbidden in the Torah than another.

Comment: Interesting question, i was wondering if you read this too. Its regarding Chukat Goyim http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/535/what-makes-something-chukat-goyim/536#536

Comment: may depend on how it is viewed in your area.

Answer (score 1):

I copied this excerpt from [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tattoos_%26_Body_Piercing)

> Rav Tuito on yeshiva.org.il writes that it is permitted to have a
>   piercing for beauty such as women have ear piercings. However,
>   piercings which are done just as self-expression or culture such as a
>   a belly ring, which isn't seen anyway, are forbidden.  In fact, Rivka
>   Imenu not only had her ears pierced, but wore a nose ring as well,
>   which was the custom at that time. (see Genesis 24:22)  In Jewish law,
>   the main determination is whether a particular body piercing is done
>   for a constructive purpose. Excessive body piercing without a
>   constructive purpose is considered making a wound, which the Torah
>   forbids. (Deut. 4:9, 15; Code of Jewish Law – C.M. 420:31). See Rashi
>   Devarim 14:1 who writes that Hashem wants Bnei Yisrael to look nice
>   without bruises or cuts.

My browser currently won't let me view the yeshiva.org, article, so I can't honestly offer a summary or my own take on this, now. B"N, after I can view this, it may give me further insight.

Comment: If he means that getting a belly piercing would be a prohibition of _chavallah_, then that would be an incredibly novelty. He would be saying that although there is no prohibition in injuring yourself for a constructive purpose, that only includes purposes approved by R. Tuito; not other purposes. I don't have the C.M. in front of me, though. If for someone for example wants to improve his / her appearance through a piercing in a place that isnt usually visible, on what grounds can R. Tuito claim that _chavallah_ (injuring someone wrongly) has been committed?

Comment: @mevaqesh, he [says](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=44085) that it is not done for beauty if the majority of people don't regard it as beautiful and it is done in a place no one can see. He doesn't outright forbid it, he just says it is difficult to find the heter for it in such a case.

Comment: @Yishai "He doesn't outright forbid it, he just says it is difficult to find the heter for it in such a case." Hmm... almost sounds like P.C. (political correctness) ;-)

Comment: but he concedes that it depends on "tzorech" not on beauty specifically. Thats why i find his ruling strange. If the Torah said: "no piercing except for beauty" then O could understand that beauty would be defied by the majority opinion. But the Torah actually forbade _needless_ piercing, so whats the difference if I have a reason to pierce myself b/c everyone else does it, or I have a reason to do it b/c many but not all do, or if I have a reason to do it because I personally like the appearance? (I am not attacking _you_ as I understand that you didnt author the response.)