# Halachic justification for forbidding playing ball

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, sport-athletics, chareidim-ultraorthodox

I was listening to a [podcast](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PmOokAO-wgs&t=1847s) with various Chareidi rabbonim discussing chinuch in Eretz Yisroel. One of them mentioned that if you enjoy playing ball you might not be for their school because they don't play ball. The reason he gave was that the Zionists placed a high priority on physical health and did so by playing ball.

My response to this is, "The Zionists placed a high priority on getting places quickly and on time, so we should assur cars to not be like the Zionists." Is there any actually halachic justification for this seemingly arbitrary minhag (for lack of a better word)?

Comment: There are alternatives to basketball

Comment: @DoubleAA but what's wrong with basketball? And what's the halachic argument for arbitrarily deciding that basketball is bad?

Comment: They said what's wrong is that it imitates the Zionists. You asked from cars but that's not a good analogy because there arent alternatives to cars.

Comment: @DoubleAA there are alternatives,like the bus and light rail systems - and the Zionists use those too in pursuit of the same objective. Who says those are allowed as well?

Comment: Good luck Yehuda

Comment: Am I missing something? What’s wrong with Zionists?

Comment: @rosends That's a hilarious edit, thank you ;p

Comment: @Yehuda [מישהו פה ירד מהפסים לבנות רכבת בירושלים? ירושלים לא דובאי! געוואלד](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxvd3B6zIsw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The reason he gave was that the Zionists placed a high priority on physical health and did so by playing ball.My response to this is, "The Zionists placed a high priority on getting places quickly and on time, so we should assur cars to not be like the Zionists." Is there any actually halachic justification for this seemingly arbitrary minhag (for lack of a better word)?*

This is a very common question asked on many things that people do not do because it is considered non-Jewish/Chukas Hahukum which is  prohibited in the Torah. (V'Yikra 20:23)וְלֹ֤א תֵֽלְכוּ֙ בְּחֻקֹּ֣ת הַגּ֔וֹי  People frequently say "non-jews drive cars and wear pants so by that logic yo:u should  prohibit them as well"

The Rishonim  give the following distinction for what is(n't) considered chukas hakum. Something that non-Jews innovated or do for  practical reasons is not considered chukas hakum. Something that non-Jews do or enjoy for *cultural* reasons   is considered  chukas hakum. Having seen and heard this topic discussed by Rabbis ranging from Satmar to YU they all seemed to accept this distinction. The only question is it's practical application. In Satmar there are far more things that they  consider to be   cultural rather than practical  than they do in YU so there are far  more things Satmar  opposes   for such reasons (including playing ball in the US) than they do in YU. Both agree however that imitating non-Jewish culture is an halachic problem

Getting back to  the original  question if playing ball is perceived as a part of Zionist culture than there would be a reason to prohibit it. There is nothing cultural about wanting to getting places quickly and on time. It is a universally high demand practical issue. Therefore no one  opposes cars even if Zionists are into them.

Note: The halachos of chukas hakum are far more complicated than written above. It's not just one simple distinction.

Comment: See [*What makes something "chukat goyim?"*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/535)

Answer (score 0):

Some chareidim are of the opinion that playing ball distracts from avodat Hashem, i.e. spiritual pursuits, or learning. Because it is deemed a "frivolous" activity. Some might also deem it not tzniout. Additionally, as this rabbi said, there is a cultural issue which they wish to distance themselves from. That being, that they put an emphasis on separating themselves from secular culture and focusing on spiritual pursuits. Recreational activities like playing ball may be seen as too secular or worldly, and therefore discouraged. There is no codified halacha; it's a sensitivity held towards judaism that they feel is correct.